# Animation problem while replacing fragment, using or not using addToBackStack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, animation

Before asking question, I apologize my poor English first.

I'm having trouble with fragment animation

My application architecture is as follows

There is only one Activity (MainActivity)

and there is one frame layout in the MainActivity.

I implemented some methods in MainActivity to replace fragments on that frame layout.

```
public void fragmentMove(Fragment dest)
{
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.addToBackStack(null);
    t.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_fade_in, R.anim.anim_fade_out, R.anim.anim_fade_in, R.anim.anim_fade_out);
    t.replace(R.id.fl_main, dest);
    t.commit();
}
public void fragmentMoveNoStack(Fragment dest)
{
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_fade_in, R.anim.anim_fade_out, R.anim.anim_fade_in, R.anim.anim_fade_out);
    t.replace(R.id.fl_main, dest);
    t.commit();
}
```

I have five fragment classes
I will call them 'fragA', 'fragB', 'fragC', 'fragD', 'fragE' each.

There is a button on each fragment to replace the fragments

for example, fragA has a button 'btn_toFragB' and I set OnClickListener to replace fragA to fragB.

the code is

```
btn_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CategoryFragment dest = new CategoryFragment(mainActivityCtx);

        ((MainActivity)ctx).fragmentMove(dest);
    }
});
```

I can navigate fragments only this order
(fragA <-> fragB <-> fragC -> fragD -> fragE -> fragC)

If I click this button, it works as I intended.

fragA fades out and fragB fades in on the frame layout

fragB -> fragC -> fragD works correctly too while only using fragmentMove method. not fragmentMoveNoStack.

I used fragmetMoveNoStack in fragD -> fragE so If I press back button on the fragE, I could get back to fragC not fragD, and it works.

But the problem is Animation.

After I get back from fragE to fragC, every fragment replacing shows fragE fade out animation.

I mean, when I replace fragB to fragC, there comes fragB fade out animation and fragC fade in animation so It looks smoothly.

But after I navigated fragE and get back to fragC, if I press back button so fragment replaces (fragC -> fragB) there comes fragE fade out animation and after that fragB fade in animation. not just fragC -> fragB, every fragment change show fragE fade out animation.

if I use fragmentMove method not fragmentMoveNoStack in fragD->fragE, there is no animation problem, but I want to make it when I press back button in fragE, there comes fragC not fragD.

The only difference between fragmentMove and fragmentMoveNoStack is addToBackStack(null);
and I think it is the reason of problem.

I want either solution or information of interaction of fragment animation and fragmentTransaction, backstacks.. etc.

Only those codes above might not include problem so I add my codes below.

this is fragC I informed
there is no fragmentMove method in this fragment. It is implemented on recyclerview

```
public class LevelFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context ctx;

    public LevelFragment(Context ctx) {
        // Required empty public constructor
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level, container, false);

        final RecyclerView rv_level = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_level);


        ImageView img_back = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.img_back);

        img_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        });

        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

there is fragmentMove in this onBindViewHolder in adapter class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RvLevelAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final View itemView = holder.itemView;

    holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cl_touchbox).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //클릭 시 해당 게임을 플레이하는 GameActivity 로 이동
            Fragment dest = new GameFragment(ctx);
            // Fragment 생성
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("id", levels[position].getId());
            dest.setArguments(bundle);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%fragmentMove is here
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ctx is Context of MainActivity
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%this adapter is called in LevelActivity I wrote above. and LevelActivity Constructor gets MainActivity Context so When I call this adapter in LevelActivity, I pass that MainActivity Context to this adapter as parameter
            ((MainActivity)ctx).fragmentMove(dest);


        }
    });
}
```

This is fragD

There is no fragmentMoveNoStack method in this class.

Method fragmentMoveNoStack is called in GameBoard Class.

I will write GameBoard Class code below this code

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context ctx;
    private Context mainActivityContext;
    LevelPlayManager lpm;

    GameBoard gameBoard;

    private int id;

    public GameFragment(Context ctx) {
        mainActivityContext = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
        ctx = fragmentView.getContext();

        gameBoard = new GameBoard(mainActivityContext, fragmentView, lpm);

        gameBoard.makeGameBoard();

        TextView tv_name = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_name.setText(name);


        ImageView img_back = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.img_back);

        img_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

            }
        });

        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

This is GameBoard Class

There is fragmentMoveNoStack

I indicated that part using '%' letter

```
public class GameBoard {

    SharedPreferences optionPref;
    boolean smartDrag;
    boolean oneLineDrag;
    boolean autoX;

    Context mainActivityContext;

    private View targetView;

    private RecyclerView rv_board;

    private GridLayoutManager glm;
    public LevelPlayManager lpm;

    ColumnIndexViewMaker civm;
    RowIndexViewMaker rivm;

    private TextView tv_stack;
    private TextView tv_count;

    private ConstraintLayout cl_count;
    private LinearLayout ll_drag;

    private ImageView img_toggle;
    private ImageView img_prev;
    private ImageView img_next;
    private ImageView img_hint;
    private ImageView img_tutorial;

    int touchStartX;
    int touchStartY;
    int touchEndX;
    int touchEndY;

    int[][] dragTemp;

    int touchMode = 0;
    int macroMode = 0;
    
    public GameBoard(Context ctx, View view, LevelPlayManager lpm)
    {
        targetView = view;
        this.lpm = lpm;
        mainActivityContext = ctx;

        initialize();
    }

    public void loadOption()
    { ~ }

    private void initialize()
    {
        dragTemp = new int[lpm.height][lpm.width];
        rv_board = targetView.findViewById(R.id.rv_board);
        //
        ~~~~~~~~
        //
        loadOption();
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    private void moveToEndFragment()
    {
        //클릭 시 해당 게임을 플레이하는 GameActivity 로 이동
        EndFragment endFragment = new EndFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", lpm.id);


        endFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        ((MainActivity)mainActivityContext).fragmentMoveNoStack(endFragment);
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    private void clickUpAction()
    {
        if(lpm.isGameEnd())
        {
            moveToEndFragment();
            setGameEnd();
        }
    }


    private BoardItemTouchListener boardTouchListener = new BoardItemTouchListener() {

        //when I press and 'release' the touch from the recycler view item, it calls moveToEndFragment
        @Override
        public void onClickUp(int pos, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)
        {
            clickUpAction();
        }
    };


    public void makeGameBoard()
    {
        glm = new GridLayoutManager(targetView.getContext(), lpm.width);

        RvBoardAdapter rba = new RvBoardAdapter(lpm.checkedSet);

        rv_board.setLayoutManager(glm);
        rv_board.addOnItemTouchListener(boardTouchListener);
        rv_board.setAdapter(rba);
    }
}
```

this is the fragE

I think code of this fragment is not important solving my problem

```
public class EndFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context ctx;


    public EndFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_end, container, false);
        ctx = fragmentView.getContext();


        return fragmentView;
    }
```

My question was so long, so I really thank you even if you just read this question but can't give me some help.

Again I'm sorry to you if there was inconvenience reading my question.

Comment: for test case use `t.add(R.id.fl_main, dest);`

Comment: thank you for feedback.
I tried t.add too and when I used it, after navigate fragE, whenever navigating other fragment, it showed fragE. not just fade out animation and dest fragment